# Broken navigation from the achievements page

Tags: bug, ios-app

Tapping on post from achievements page doesn't lead to open a post:

> [image: achievements]

I can tap on any item in achievements page or refresh page with no result. On the image above I tap on second item. Title says that I on the answer for post from the first item.

Happens only once for me.

- App Version: 1.6.5.1
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)